# Merge a data.table and a list

Tags: r, list, data.table

I want to add a list into my data.table. Lets consider this data.table:

```
dt = data.table(id = 1:3)

lst <- list()
lst[[2]] <- cbind(a=10:12, b=5:7)

dt[-nrow(dt), lst:=lst]

dt
#   id               lst
#1:  1                  
#2:  2 10,11,12, 5, 6, 7
#3:  3
```

Is it possible to "unlist" the lst, so that the data.table will look like this?

```
      id  a  b       
1.0:  1                  
2.0:  2 
2.1:  2   10 5
2.2:  2   11 6
2.3:  2   12 7
3.0:  3
```

There is also a speed issue, as the data I am working with consists of billions of rows.

Comment: Why not rbindlist(lst, idcol=‘id’)[dt, on=.(id)]. Not in front of computer to test though. You might get warning about use.names. Might need to set to TRUE or FALSE depending on your needs

Comment: Getting this: Error: unexpected input in "rbindlist(lst, idcol=‘"

Comment: How do you decide which rows to attach values to? Why row 2 is empty?

Comment: I want to keep the original dt, so row 2.0 just have id=2. Row 2.1 to 2.3 should consist of the data in the list.

Comment: What about `rbind(dt, data.table(id=2, a=10:12, b=5:7), fill = TRUE)[order(id)]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option as mentioned in comment:

```
rbindlist(list(dt, 
        rbindlist(lapply(lst, as.data.table), idcol='id')), 
    use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)[order(id)]
```

output:

```
   id  a  b
1:  1 NA NA
2:  2 NA NA
3:  2 10  5
4:  2 11  6
5:  2 12  7
6:  3 NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a `lapply` across the list, and add the rows to an empty row if the item in the list is non-empty:

```
dt <- data.table(id = 1:3)

lst <- list()
lst[[2]] <- cbind(a=10:12, b=5:7)

create_table <- function(x, lst) {
  if (!is.null(lst[[x]])) {
    # Empty row plus items in list
    rbindlist(
      list(data.table(id = x), data.table(id = x, lst[[x]])), 
      use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE
    )
  } else {
    data.table(id = x)
  }
}

aux_lst <- rbindlist(
  lapply(seq(lst), create_table, lst = lst), 
  use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE
)

aux_lst[dt, on = .(id)] # Keeps all IDs in dt
```

If the list is named and the id column relates to those names, then replace `seq` with `names`

Answer (score 1):

Some reformatting is needed, but you can use `rbindlist`:

```
# create all entries in lst
length(lst) <- nrow(dt)

# identify table sizes
lens     = sapply(lst, NROW)

# use data.tables instead of matrices
# fill empty tables with a blank template
template = data.table(a=NA_real_, b=NA_real_)
dtlist   = replace(lapply(lst, as.data.table), lens == 0, list(template))

# expand dt to match tables
replens  = pmax(lens, 1L)    
cbind(dt[rep(1:.N, replens)], rbindlist(dtlist))

   id  a  b
1:  1 NA NA
2:  2 10  5
3:  2 11  6
4:  2 12  7
5:  3 NA NA
```

Comment: we both miss out the empty row for row 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(id = 1:3)

lst <- list()
lst[[2]] <- cbind(a=10:12, b=5:7)

unique(rbindlist(lapply(1:length(lst), function(i) {
  data.table(id = i, lst[[i]])[dt, on = .(id)]
}
  ), fill=TRUE))[order(id)]
```

> ```
>    id  a  b
> 1:  1 NA NA
> 2:  2 NA NA
> 3:  2 10  5
> 4:  2 11  6
> 5:  2 12  7
> 6:  3 NA NA
> ```